# java.sql.Time exception

Tags: java, gson, classnotfoundexception, java-9

does anybody met something like that? 
After switching to JAVA 9 I faced such problem

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Time
    at com.google.gson.Gson.<init>(Gson.java:240)
    at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.create(GsonBuilder.java:569)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.json.gson.GsonJSONConverter.<init>(GsonJSONConverter.java:50)
    at net.thucydides.core.reports.json.gson.GsonJSONConverter$$FastClassByGuice$$6794eb79.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Time
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 42 more
```

I tried different java version, also gson library was not updated, I mean the same package was working on java 8. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to add the [Java SQL module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.sql-summary.html).

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza  like jar or maven dependency?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza I've read articles but didn't get how to add sql module

Comment: Create a module file that contains `module <modulename>; requires java.sql;`. It's explained in the article, in section *Module Declarations*.

Comment: Be aware, maybe you'll need to add more modules.

Comment: seems like java/sql.TIme is requested by com.google.gson.Gson. So I can't add dependency on module for this lib

Comment: The java.sql module is mapped to the platform class loader. Is it possible that Gson is using its own URLClassLoader with `null` as the parent. That would explain the exception in the question.

Comment: @Alan Bateman do you have any thoughts how to resolve issue?

Comment: Did you manage to track down the code that is creating the URLClassLoader with a "null" parent?

Answer (score 8):

for my case it start works after i run it with JAR manifest configured

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Add java.sql to your `module-info.java` file:

```
module MODULE_NAME {
    ...
    requires java.sql;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

java.sql is a module, 
[java9 sql module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.sql-summary.html)

Try:

```
java --module-path lib --add-modules java.sql
```

Comment: can you please clarify step by step how to add it? Coz line you provided doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Gson has default adapters for some SQL types (one of that is `java.sql.Time`). Since Java 9 the SQL classes are in their own module ([`java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/module-summary.html)). Most likely that module was not included by default for you when you executed your program.

However, starting with [Gson 2.8.9](https://github.com/google/gson/releases/tag/gson-parent-2.8.9) the dependency on the SQL types is optional. You can use Gson without any issues, even if they are not present.

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me. IDE:
Run-> Edit Configurations and in the "Shorten command line" field select the "JAR manifest"